# Microsoft Edge CORS fetch fails

Tags: cors, fetch, microsoft-edge

I have a web application making requests to an API that lives on another local server so the requests are identified as CORS requests in Chrome and Firefox and work there. But in Edge all I get is this weird behavior that logs this in Network tab in developer tools and actually does nothing:

[Fetch request logged in Edge's developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AJcq.png)

As shown above the request contains no headers and the response is empty. My code is pretty simple and goes like this:

```
fetch("http://192.168.10.164:15622/api/Users/LoginUser", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ UserName:"hi", UserPass:"123" })
        });
```

Comment: Force-reload the document or clear your browser cache — because the **Received** column in the screenshot shows *(from cache)*, which seems to indicate your browser is loading the document from its cache rather than fetching it from the server.

Comment: Hi @thesdev I'm having the same issue. Happens in In-private as well, so definitely not a caching issue. Any luck fixing it?

Comment: @Boland Unfortunately no :/

Comment: @thesdev are you testing your website from localhost? Try something else by adding a HOSTS file entry, e.g. "test.local" that points to 127.0.0.1 and use that one. That has solved it in my case.

Comment: @Boland Actually the API I'm having problem with is hosted on a different computer on my LAN. Your suggestion didn't work unfortunately. [screenshot of failed request](http://uupload.ir/files/vgjw_edge_request_fail.png) [screenshot of hosts](http://uupload.ir/files/qbrg_hosts.png) Thanks for the suggestion.